# Updating several columns of a data frame with another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am a newbie user of R and I got stuck with the following problem.

I am trying to merge over 2 data frames. I have 5 by-variables while merging and several other overlapping columns in two data frame. I am trying to update these overlapping variables in one data frame with the other. I have searched this website and found some answers but none of them are efficient in my case. The reason is I have several columns to be updated and secondly, as I will be doing this merging 100 monthly data in the end, I dont always know the names of the overlapping columns. The previous solutions generally update by writing the name of each column in the code but I am trying to find a way to do it without using their name.

As an example, lets say..

```
tuse1
age d1 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5
1   89 2  3  3  NA NA
2   34 3  4  5  NA NA

tuse2
age d1 a1 a2  a3 a4 a5 a6
1   89 2  3   3  3  6  2
2   34 3  4   5  4  7  2
3   32 4  3   3  6  6  6
```

I wanna merge tuse1 and tuse2 by age and d1. I want a code that can update tuse1 NA variables with tuse2 without using the column names in the code.

Here is my code for that:

```
key = c("age", "d1")
comNam = intersect(names(tuse1), names(tuse2))
comNam = comNam[3:length(comNam)]
merge_second_age = merge(x = tuse1, y = tuse2, all = TRUE, by = c(key))

for(i in comNam){
  left <- paste(i, ".x", sep="")
  right <- paste(i, ".y", sep="")

merge_second_age$i = with(merge_second_age, factor(ifelse(is.na(left), right, left)))
merge_second_age$left = NULL; merge_second_age$right = NULL
merge_second_age$left = NULL; merge_second_age$right = NULL

}
```

This code seems working without any error but unfortunately does not give the desired output.

The desired output I am looking at is as follows:

```
 age d1 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
  1  89 2  3  3   3 6  2
  2  34 3  4  5   4 7  2
```

I would appreciate any help.

Best
Dilsat

Comment: can you provide your desired output?

Comment: can you give an example desired output?  For instance, what happens for age=2, d1=34 for the 'a2' value which differs between the two dfs?

Comment: Hello @m0h3n, Thanks a lot for the quick replies. I have just edited my question and added desired output. Keep in mind that I am really trying to avoid using variable names in the code as in original data set they are a lot.I want my code to find these overlapping columns and update them. Thanks million times! :)

Comment: Hello @jalapic, Thanks a lot for the quick reply. I have just edited my question and added desired output. Keep in mind that I am really trying to avoid using variable names in the code as in original data set they are a lot.I want my code to find these overlapping columns and update them. Thanks million times! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your `key` is `age` and `d1`, this is what you can do:

```
common=tuse2[intersect(match(tuse1$age,tuse2$age), match(tuse1$d1,tuse2$d1)),]
```

This is what you can do if your `key` length is more than `2`:

```
common=tuse2[Reduce(intersect, list(
match(tuse1$age,tuse2$age), 
match(tuse1$d1,tuse2$d1),
match(tuse1$a1,tuse2$a1),
match(tuse1$a2,tuse2$a2),
match(tuse1$a3,tuse2$a3)))
,]
```

which will give the same output your provided:

```
  age d1 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6
1   1 89  2  3  3  3  6  2
2   2 34  3  4  5  4  7  2
```

That is, `tuse1` is merged with `tuse2` conditional on `age` and `d1`. Moreover, `NA` values in `tuse1` are replaced with respective values from `tuse2` provided that `age` and `d1` are the same.

**DATA**

```
tuse1=structure(list(age = 1:2, d1 = c(89L, 34L), a1 = 2:3, a2 = 3:4, 
    a3 = c(3L, 5L), a4 = c(NA, NA), a5 = c(NA, NA)), .Names = c("age", 
"d1", "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

tuse2=structure(list(age = 1:3, d1 = c(89L, 34L, 32L), a1 = 2:4, a2 = c(3L, 
4L, 3L), a3 = c(3L, 5L, 3L), a4 = c(3L, 4L, 6L), a5 = c(6L, 7L, 
6L), a6 = c(2L, 2L, 6L)), .Names = c("age", "d1", "a1", "a2", 
"a3", "a4", "a5", "a6"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again. However, I have 5 key variables in my original data set. Intersect function works with only two variables as far as I understand. Do you have any idea how I can handle this issue?